# What should my reverse DNS be for my inhouse email server?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record

So I have an inhouse exchange server for the domain `visaustralia.com`.
(email addresses are `email@visaustralia.com`)

And when checking the reverse DNS of my static IP address with http://www.whatsmyip.us/reversedns.php I get

```
vis1247147.lnk.telstra.net
```

Which is likely from my ISP (telstra).

What do they need to change it to? `visaustralia.com`? I tried calling them but after a total of 6 hours in the phone with different people and waiting to be transferred, no one could help me and they didnt even seem to understand what I needed.

Do I need to request them to add a PTR record? Or what would be the terminology of what they need to do and to what setting?

Comment: Most ISPs don't really like to do that. It has multiple reasons, mainly relating to their internal administration, and because such ip ranges are for home users. If you want a revdns entry for your server, use their server hosting solutions (which is more costly, of course, but in this case you will be able to reach competent people relatively fast).

Answer (score 3):

You can contact your ISP (telstra) to set PTR record or Reverse DNS record for your mail server IP address.

PTR Hostname can be any FQDN based on your domain visaustralia.com.

For Example: mail.visaustralia.com

Ideally, you should set PTR record to FQDN you have set at **outgoing mail server** for domain visaustralia.com

Comment: Well I'm not sure if that is the FQDN or how to check the outgoing mail server, but our online exchange server is remote.visaustralia.com/exchange.

Answer (score 1):

What's the FQDN on your Send Connector? That's what you should set the PTR record to.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if that is the FQDN or where to check the send connector, but our online exchange server is remote.visaustralia.com/exchange.